# Efficient way get index of empty tuple with Python

Tags: python, indexing, tuples

The objective is to extract index of empty tuple.
May I know whether there is more efficient way than the code below. For actual case, the tuple length is greater in magnitude than given below.

```
tup=(('AT',), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ('UR',), ('UR',),())
outpt= [idx for idx,i in enumerate(tup) if not i]
```

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14]

Comment: That's an efficient way to do it. You may be able to squeeze a bit of speed out of [cython](https://cython.org) but python does fast list processing.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is probably the best one for the general case, but if the empty tuples are infrequent then repeated calls to `index()` may be more efficient (taken from https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-find-all-indexes-of-an-item-in-a-list/):

```
def get_index_positions(list_of_elems, element):
    ''' Returns the indexes of all occurrences of give element in
    the list- listOfElements '''
    index_pos_list = []
    index_pos = 0
    while True:
        try:
            # Search for item in list from indexPos to the end of list
            index_pos = list_of_elems.index(element, index_pos)
            # Add the index position in list
            index_pos_list.append(index_pos)
            index_pos += 1
        except ValueError as e:
            break
    return index_pos_list
```

which you could use as follows

```
>>> get_index_positions(tup, ())
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14]
```

Edit: you could also try [numpy](https://numpy.org/) which may be faster

```
>>> np.where(np.array(tup, dtype=object).astype(bool) == 0)
(array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 14]),)
```